# Passive of : We should adhere to our decisions

Tags: passive-voice

[image]

Out of the given options which one is a better choice for passive voice of adhere ? I chose option D but the exercise has chosen option C. Isn't it incorrect because the *by us* phrase is repeated which sounds a little awkward.

Comment: All of them are awkward, but C is the only one that is not actively wrong.

Comment: Sentence C is a little awkward, but there's nothing wrong about repeating *by us*, because it's used to refer to two different things.

Answer (score 1):

> Our decisions should be adhered to by us.

is how I'd state the passive there.

Apart from C, which is grammatical, all of the other options are ungrammatical, as Daniel said in his comment.

One of the problems with such exercises with the passive is that they often present truly bizarre constructions as models.

There are thousands of scenarios where the passive is used idiomatically. Why so few of them appear in these exercises is a mystery.